# How to select only groups of records based on value?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

How do I select only matching MDM groups where Score = 1 occurs in the group? So I start with:

```
            Score   MDM
            0       1001961
            0       1001961
            0       1001961
            0       1100406
            1       1100794
            0       1100794
            1       1101109
            0       1101109
```

But I should end up with:

```
            Score   MDM
            1       1100794
            0       1100794
            1       1101109
            0       1101109
```

Comment: Read about EXISTS. It will make this really simple.

Comment: Thanks, that was a big help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use `exists`:

```
select score, mdm
from yourtable t
where exists (
    select 1
    from yourtable t2
    where t.mdm = t2.mdm and t2.score = 1
)
```

Comment: Thanks, this works, but after reading about EXISTS I'm still not clear how it knows how to select the correct groups.

Comment: Okay, after burning a few more brain cells I get it now. Glad to have this in my toolset. Thanks!